# Does $P(f(X) \leq x) = P(X \leq f^{-1}(x))$ holds in general?

Tags: probability

Let's say we have an invertible function $f(x)$, is it always true that

$$
P(f(X) \leq x) = P(X \leq f^{-1}(x))
$$
?

If not, what properties does $f$ need to have to have this equality hold?

Comment: No,unless$f$ ismonotone increasing

Comment: @OliverDiaz Do you have a source for this in the context of probability? I've been trying to find something but haven't had much luck

Comment: It is an relatively obvious fact, to preserve order you need the function to be monotone increasing

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, $f = -x$ wouldn't work. It needs to be increasing. Otherwise, the inequality would "turn around" for example.
More formally, $f(x) \leq y \iff x\in f^{-1}(-\infty,y)$ and you want $f^{-1}(-\infty,y) = (-\infty,f^{-1}(y))\ \ \forall y$. Then necessarily, for every $y$ we must have $f(y') \leq f(y) \ \ \forall y'\leq y$. If $f$ is strictly increasing (we need strict for it to be invertible) then this condition is also met.

**EDIT:**
If f is an increasing function (not necessarily strictly) then you can define $$A_y = \lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}: f(x)\geq y\rbrace $$
And $g(y) = \text{inf}\ A_y$ to be your generalized inverse, then what you want is that:$$X\leq g(y) \iff f(X) \leq y$$
You can prove that $g$ is increasing and if $f$ is continuous then $g(y)\in A_y$ and $f(g(y))= y$ (the latter using Bolzano and some tiny work). This way:
$(\implies)$ if $f$ is continuous then $f(X) \leq f(g(y)) = y \leq y$
$(\impliedby)$ if $X > g(y)$ then since f is increasing and continuous $f(X) \geq f(g(y)) \geq y$ because $g(y)\in A_y$

If f is not continuous, for example a step function $f(x) =\begin{cases}0 \quad x\in(-\infty,0) \\
1 \quad x\in[0,\infty)\\
\end{cases}$
Then you can't necessarily get $f(g(y)) \leq y$ since $f(g(0.5)) = f(0) = 1 \nleq 0.5$ (perhaps there is a way to caracterize this functions but I don't know it). And for $g(y)\in A_y$ you need some kind of right-continuousness otherwise the following function fails $h(x) =\begin{cases}0 \quad x\in(-\infty,0] \\
1 \quad x\in(0,\infty)\\
\end{cases}$

Comment: Does it need to be just "increasing" or "strictly increasing?"

Comment: strictly increasing for it to be invertible, otherwise you wouldn't really have that $f^{-1}$. Perhaps you could use a kind of generalized inverse and it would work too. I would have to think about it

Comment: Hmm, you could have $f^{-1}$ if it was increasing, but not strictly, it's just it wouldn't be unique right?

Comment: Just finished the edit